# Comparing two csv files with different lengths but output only the line where it matches the same value in two different column

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've been trying to compare two csv file using simple shell script but I think the code that I was using is not doing it's job. what I want to do is, compare the two files using Column 6 from first.csv and Column 2 in second.csv and when it matches, it will output the line from first.csv. see below as an example

**first.csv**

```
1,0,3210820,0,536,7855712
1,0,3523340820,0,36,53712
1,0,321023423i420,0,336,0255712
1,0,321082234324,0,66324,027312
```

**second.csv**

```
14,7855712,Whie,Black
124,7855712,Green,Black
174,1197,Black,Orange
1284,98132197,Yellow,purple
35384,9811123197,purple,purple
13354,0981123131197,green,green
183434,0811912313127,white,green
```

**Output should be from the first file:**

```
1,0,3210820,0,536,7855712
```

I've been using the code below.

```
cat first.csv | while read line    
do    
  cat second.csv | grep $line > output_file    
done
```

please help. Thank you

Comment: According to which rule can the output be derived from the input? I suggest that you add the algorithm for this problem to your question. For your concrete example, the desired output could simply be achieved by doing a `head -n 1 first.csv`.

Comment: I need to match the column 6 from the first.csv and column 2 from the second.csv when it matches, the output should be from the first csv. tried to reverse it with my initial code but it does not work

Comment: @Jiggen, Your output is `1,0,3210820,0,536,7855712`  but I can't see `536` in input?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry typo error, it should be COLUMN 6 to COLUMN 2.

Comment: So your problem really is: _Print all lines from first.csv, where the content of field 6 can be found in field 2 of some row in second.csv_. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jiggen, This is very commonly asked question on SO, you can try like: `awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{arr[$6]=$0;next} ($2 in arr){print arr[$2]}' first.csv second.csv` once.

Comment: @user1934428 that is correct sir. I'm having a hard time constructing the logic since I am a newbie in coding.

Comment: @Jiggen, Your welcome. But do always a proper search on Google OR in stack overflow, you will find Good help, as I mentioned this is very commonly asked question, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: If this is correct, then I would write the question in this way, instead of letting the people guess what you mean! After all, a program can be written only after we have a precise definition of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but here is what I think you want:

```
cat first.csv | while read LINE; do
    VAL=`echo "$LINE" | cut -d, -f6`
    grep -q "$VAL" second.csv && echo $LINE
done
```

The first line in the loop extracts the 6th field from the line and stores it in VAL. The next line checks (quietly), if VAL occurs in second.csv and if so, outputs the line.

Note that grep will check for any occurence in second.csv, not only in field 2. To check only against field 2, change it to:

```
    cut -d, -f2 second.csv | grep -q "$VAL" && echo $LINE
```

Unrelated to your question I would like to comment, that those things can much more efficiency be solved in a language like python.

Answer (score 0):

Well... If you have bash with *process substitution* you can treat all the 2nd fields in `second.csv` (with a `$` appended to anchor the search at the end of the line) as input from a file. Then using `grep -f` match data from the 2nd column of `second.csv` with the end of the line in `first.csv` doing what you intend.

You can use the `<(process)` form to redirect the 2nd field as a file using:

```bash
grep -f <(awk -F, '{print $2"$"}' second.csv) first.csv
```

**Example Output**

With the data you show in `first.csv` and `second.csv` you get:

```
1,0,3210820,0,536,7855712
```

Adding the `"$"` anchor as part of the 2nd field from `second.csv` should satisfy the match only in the 6th field (end of line) in `first.csv`.

The benefit here being there is but a single call to `grep` and `awk`, not an additional subshell spawned per-iteration. Doesn't matter with small files like your sample input, but with millions of lines, we are talking hours (or days) of processing time difference.